# Security Vulnerability : What is the error in this piece of code?

Tags: c, security, integer-overflow

I was reading [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321424778) on my own , just for fun , and came across the following question :

> This code has a security vulnerability ; Can you find and fix it? :

```
  bool isValidAddition(unsigned short x, unsigned short y) 
 {
     if(x + y < x)
         return false;
     else 
         return true;
 }
```

Can someone help me , recognize the vulnerability ?

Comment: I don't think any issue here. Can you do some research and then ask this question?

Comment: The only thing I see that's wrong with the function is that it will never return `false`.

Comment: You'll need to insert a cast `(unsigned short)(x+y)<x` since the addition causes a promotion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that the following points are true as per the `C Standard` :

> - sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)
> - sizeof(short) >= 2 bytes , sizeof(int) >= 2 bytes, sizeof(long) >= 4 bytes
> - There is an implicit integer promotion of operand data types used in arithmetic expressions which is done by the compiler

So in the code snippet above do the following :

Change

```
if(x + y < x)
```

to

```
if((unsigned short)(x + y) < x)
```

This will worrk if int is 4 (or >2) bytes

Hope this helps :)